# Publishing issues for Silverlight enabled wcf service on iis7 and windows server 2008

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis-7, publish, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a silverlight application with wcf service self hosted in it.When I publish the the application with service on iis7 on windows server 2008,I cant see any data from service in my application(Service is not getting called).While debugging application I can see the data coming from servcie(sql server table data).Also when I publish the same application on my local system i.e. IIS-7 on windows7,I am able to access the service and data,on any system in network as well as on system where it is published.
I have made all the possible setting on iis7 which I found and also url for service is correct everywhere(dynamically generated),as I have published it successfully on iis 7 in windows 7 ,only the application is not accessing wcf when published on iis in windows server.
Also I have gone through all posts available here,but found no exact solution.
Settings for iis 7 and wcf i have done are

- -aspnet_iisreg.exe(installed)
- -all required setting in windows features turn on and off.
- -on iis,all permissions are set for required user.
- -Setting are done in mime type and handler mapping.
- -I can browse successfully the wcf service with no error,and the same url is used while calling service from application.

Here is a piece of my code,where I am generating service endpoint url dynamically.

```
 Try

        busyIndicator.IsBusy = True
        mService.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(DynamicEndpointHelper.ResolveEndpointUrl(mService.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString(),
    App.Current.Host.Source.ToString()))            
        mService.GetProjectNamesAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Class DynamicEndpointHelper
    ' Put the development server site URL including the trailing slash
    ' This should be same as what's set in the Dropthings web project's
    ' ' properties as the URL of the site in development server
    Private Const BaseUrl As String = "http://localhost:1632/"

    Public Shared Function ResolveEndpointUrl(endpointUrl As String, xapPath As String) As String
        Dim baseUrl__1 As String = xapPath.Substring(0, xapPath.IndexOf("ClientBin"))
        Dim relativeEndpointUrl As String = endpointUrl.Substring(BaseUrl.Length)
        Dim dynamicEndpointUrl As String = baseUrl__1 & relativeEndpointUrl
        Return dynamicEndpointUrl
    End Function
End Class
```

web.config part:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="testing.Web.Service1.basicHttpBinding" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="testing.Web.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="testing.Web.Service1" />       
      </service>   
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

ServiceReference.ClientConfig part

```
    <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>       
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1632/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" contract="sr_service1.Service1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? If your silverlight self-hosts something, that would run on your clients computer. That's neither what you want nor what he will allow.

Comment: Can you add the part where you host it?

Comment: I meant where you *host* it. You said you self-host it. In silverlight. That means you have a line in silverlight where you open up a service host. Maybe you don't self-host it?

Comment: @ nvoigt oh ..i thought this is what self hosting.I have added wcf service in    .web project of my application.I publish this application with wcf in it. After publishing the app,I browse to path of wcf service from active directory.That path is same as I am generating endpoint address dynamically.

Comment: So, do you get any errors? Is your dynamic url correct (can you call it in IE for example?)

Comment: @nvoigt yes url is correct,I can see the service without any errors in any browser.Also I am able to run my application after publishing in iis7 on windows 7,but not on windows server.

Comment: Do you have the clientaccesspolicy.xml in place?

Comment: @Rob J  Yes I have clientaccesspolicy and crossdomain xml at root as well as in my .web folder of app.

Comment: Have you tried running fiddler to see what the request from the Silverlight application looks like?

Comment: @Rob J I checked fiddler ,there is no url for wcf service on server.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint address the sivlerlight application is trying to call is defined in the ServiceReference.clientconfig as: http://localhost:1632/Service1.svc.  I assume that is not the actual deployed address you want to use.  See this [article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/05/managing-service-references-in-silverlight-applications-for-different-environments.aspx) for how to dynamically assign the service endpoint address.

Comment: I have generated endpoint address dynamically,as its working fine when I publish my application on iis7 with windows7(i.e my local machine). But when I publish the application on production server(i.e. iis7 with windows server 2008) its not fetching data. Now I am able to see the service url in fiddler also,but no data is coming from wcf.